# Is it possible to embed the Manipulate into a WordPress post?

Tags: manipulate, interactive, cloud-deploy, wordpress

I have a `Manipulate` object: `Manipulate[n, {n, 1, 100}]`. I want to put it in my WordPress blog post. Should I `CloudDeploy` it as below first?

```
CloudDeploy[Manipulate[n, {n, 1, 100}]]
```

Let say I obtain the below link as output, how can I make use of it?

```
CloudDeploy[https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/abcd12345-ab12-ab12-abc123456789]
```

I found a [related video](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?v=455), but that was created in 2011 and was still using Mathematica 8. Besides, it is for the entire CDF file (not just a `Manipulate`), and it also hasn't mentioned what plugin (some Wolfram plugin?) is required to be installed in WordPress.

How can I get it done? Many thanks!

Comment: [webMathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/)

Comment: Also, I wonder if the [Notebook Embedder](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframNotebookEmbedder/) can be used with WordPress?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an iframe within wordpress. The ones created here are using iframe within wordpress: https://sameradeeb-new.srv.ualberta.ca/introduction-to-numerical-analysis/finding-roots-of-equations/

Based on my limited experience, I recommend using only one iframe per page.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you set up the site and deployed the Manipulate functions?  Can you also confirm that the site is still working?  As of today (6/11/2020) the Manipulates sit with the "Starting interactivity..." popup indefinitely.

Comment: I think the issue is probably the number of iframes per page. I am finding embedding clouddeployed pages within iframes to be finicky. The following page has only one clouddeploy and it should work fine: https://sameradeeb-new.srv.ualberta.ca/introduction-to-numerical-analysis/taylor-series/#taylor%E2%80%99s-theorem10 . In our new site, I am opting for links that open in new tabs rather than iframes which seem to be more stable: https://engcourses-uofa.ca/books/numericalanalysis/finding-roots-of-equations/bracketing-methods/#bisection-method2

Comment: FWIW, I used [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-iframe/) and the documentation from `EmbedCode` to get a minimal working example.  Per your suggestions, I didn't try more than one iframe on the page.

Comment: Can you share the link? thx.

Comment: Right now it is on a private page for testing.  I can update when that changes.